# Call function of CWinThread in main thread

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I am working with CDialog in MFC.
In my dialog, I create a ui-thread:

```
CWinthread *threadCom = dynamic_cast<MyThreadClass*>(AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(MyThreadClass)));
```

Somewhere in my dialog class, I write:
threadCom->MyFunction();

My question is: "MyFuction()" is executed in main thread of dialog or ui-thread

---

**Update after comment of  AlexanderVX**

For example, when user clicks on button on dialog

```
CMyDialog::OnBtnClicked() { threadCom->MyFunction(); }
```

Comment: Of course the function can only be executed on the thread where you execute it from. In your case it is UI thread. I bet your question is not an example of a good question, btw. What is MyFunction? The member of CWinthread class? So, just a function call.

Comment: Sorry about unclear example, MyFuction() is a public method of MyThreadClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Calling a function" like calling a member function of a class is an action in your current thread.

If you want that Actions are executed asynchronously in the other thread you need some communication between the threads.

If the second thread has also a UI, it is possible to use messages (PostMessage) to inform the thread about an action. PostMessage is also a good way to inform the main thread about results from the worker thread.

If you need to transfer data too (more than a DWORD), you need a more complex data exchange that should be thread safe too.